# Can anyone explain this complicated pointer expression?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller, cortex-m

I found this below code line which is a function call at driver library. I am trying to understand this pointer expression. But it is hard to understand.

```
ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
```

Below code lines are definition of components of above code.

```
#define SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA     0xf0000800  // GPIO A
#define ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable                                            \
    ((void (*)(uint32_t ui32Peripheral))ROM_SYSCTLTABLE[6])
#define ROM_SYSCTLTABLE         ((uint32_t *)(ROM_APITABLE[13]))   
#define ROM_APITABLE            ((uint32_t *)0x01000010)
```

Comment: This is a function pointer cast, it means you can use `ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable` as if it were the name of a function which returns `void` and takes a `uint32_t` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ROM_SYSCTLTABLE[6]
```

holds a some data.That data is memory location where a function is stored.This function takes argument of type `uint32_t` and returns nothing. When you write

```
ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
```

It means that you are calling that function by passing argument as  `0xf0000800`

Answer (score 1):

It is using the data in the seventh entry of ROM_SYSCTLTABLE as a function pointer (the address of a function), calling it and passing SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIDA as its uint32_t parameter.  Any value returned is not available to the caller.

Comment: It's seventh entry of `ROM_SYSCTLTABLE`, not `ROM_APITABLE`. And it is not a pointer. It is an address stored as `uint32_t` which is cast as function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Entire line forms a function call with the address of function is in *(*(0x010001d)+6) which is type casted to take one uint32_t as argument and no return value and 0xf0000800 is the values passed.

```
( (void (*)(uint32_t ui32Peripheral) )(  -->TypeCasted to take uint32_t as parameter
         *( (uint32_t*) ( *(((uint32_t *)0x01000010) + 13)) ) + 6)  --> Function Address
     ) (0xf0000800);   --> Function Parameter ( as per the type casting)
```